# Mongo: lost connection & collections

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I was running a Rails rake task overnight on my local machine in order to seed my Mongo collection. It had probably generated about 45,000 records before I received the following exception:

```
Operation failed with the following exception: connection closed

Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
```

I am on a Mac OS X, so I attempted `mongo` and received the following:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

So I ran `mongod` thinking that this would simply start up the process. It now appears to have indexed new collections, because all of them are empty. Did I overwrite them, or might they still exist somewhere?

I ran `ls /data/db` and I see `myapp_development.0` and `myapp_development.ns`. Does that tell me anything?

Comment: I restarted my system and now everything is fine???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your MongoDB data directory was set to somewhere other than the default (/data/db).  Restarting would likely have started mongod with the correct --dbpath.

For example, if you followed a MAMP install guide the suggestion may have been to put the data directory inside /Applications/MAMP/db/mongo.

You should be able to find the dbpath used by running the following command in the mongo JS shell:

```
db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts')
```

Look for a parsed setting for "dbpath".

Comment: The result of that is `/usr/local/var/mongodb`. I don't understand why my `rails c` would connect to an empty db, and then connect to the full db after restart. Is it possible that my auto-start Mongo is different from running `mongod` after it crashes?

Comment: If you start mongod without any options it will be assuming the data directory (dbpath) is `/data/db`.  If that directory doesn't exist or isn't writeable, mongod will display an error message and refuse to start.  As long as the data directory exists with appropriate read/write permissions, mongod will create and use data files in that directory.  If the data directory is empty, that's effectively the same as starting from a fresh install: none of your databases/collections will exist until you start inserting data.

Comment: The auto-start script you have is doing the equivalent of running `mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb`.

If you wanted to save a consistent set of options for starting from the command line, you could specify them in a config file instead, eg `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf`.  Options are documented in [File Based Configuration](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration).